# How to mark a variable/data structure to check who changed it in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Trying to find a nasty issue in my code (Unity project).

Basically I create a list; with 10 elements with a custom class. I later use this list, but when I try to access it, all 10 elements became null.

I did something wrong, which is evident, but I can't track down where the elements of the list are set to null; so I was wondering if Visual studio has a way to mark a variable, and can let me run the debug while attached to Unity, so when that list is touched, it will actually stop execution like with a breakpoint, so I can actually see what did call the code that set the elements to null.

Is this possible or do I have to follow my code piece to piece?

Comment: Hmm, not fully sure that there is something out of box that will allow to do that with collection, but you can always create a wrapper collection that wraps all indexer/remove/add methods and put breakpoints/logging in wrapper methods. Then you just expose that collection instead of the simple list.

Comment: I see; that would be quite time consuming I believe. I did run the debug from when the collection is created, to the end of the function and the data is there...all the entry are not null. Then nothing else in my code, is apparently calling that collection (I did put a breakpoint on the function that clean up that collecion and it never gets called); so at this point I am a bit confused about how to find what is setting each entry in the collection to null.

Comment: Replacing with wrapper will be easy (assuming that you expose `IList<T>` and not the `List<T>`). And if you can't find the culprit with breakpoints while debugging, then just add some logging to the production environment.

Comment: There are also some [AOP solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) that will do the same without a need of custom wrapper, but I am not very experienced with them. And the gist will still be the same.

Comment: Thanks Eugene; this is totally new to me; it is my first time debugging a Unity application, and it is not really that simple as expected.

Comment: There are at least three interpretations of the state after the problem. Deciding which of these, or something else, will help you locate the fault. (1) The list still has 10 elements but all are `null`. (2) The list is there but has zero elements. (3) The list is null.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the issue is manifesting always in the same way: the list still has 10 elements but they are null. The other 2 case never happen. I believe it is related to MonoBehaviour; since the issue happen only when the class is declared as MonoBehaviour.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I did find somehow a solution.

In visual studio, on the bottom ther eis a panel, which show "error list", "output" and "find symbol". If I place a breakpoint somewhere in the code, that area change, and the area tabs change in "Autos", "Locals", "Threads", "Modules" and "Watch1".

The last tab allow you to type an object in it, which will be then watched while the debugger is on. I did add my object that contain the list that get set to null, and I was able to follow the changes in that object (although it happens only while you are stepping through the code, so it works only if you step through the code from the scripts, in Unity).

Thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [code contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.110).aspx) and place an invariant on the count of elements, and include non null condition for each element as well. 
Code contracts engine will re-write your code, and place appropriate validations into every place that modifies state, that could potentially break the invariant. 
So, hopefully, you will get an error as soon as your elements become null, so you will be able to see when **exactly** that happens, and perhaps that will help you to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Ironstone; I am reading about it and trying to understand how it works. Debugging with Unity is quite daunting, since once that it goes in its own game loop, and out of your scripts, you can't really do much

Answer (score 0):

Use "Find All References" for finding all locations where selected variable/method is using.

With this you can set conditional break point, which will break only if variable is null.

Comment: Thanks Fabio, I did that and placed a break point on every occurrence where the variable is used; and the issue happen between the creation of the list (at the end of the function the list is full and just fine), and the first time that it is read, so I can retrieve the data. There is nothing in between that call or access that list. Which is why I am banging my head on the desk, trying to figure out how this could happen